# SWFobject - how to automatically redirect

Tags: actionscript-3

Excuse me if this is an obvious question,

How can you use SWFobject to automatically redirect to another URL -
NOT add an a href but physically load another URL ?

I'm using SWFobject 2 at the moment .

-- the SWFobject code ...

swfobject.embedSWF("MYSITE.swf", "myAlternativeContent", "850", "700", "9.0.0", false, flashvars, params, attributes);

--- 2 tricks I've tried in the myAlternativeContent DIV ...

## 1 ...

```
    <div id="myAlternativeContent">
          <meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url=http://www.NOFLASHSITE.com">
    </div>
```

## 2 ...

```
    <div id="myAlternativeContent">
          <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            window.location="http://www.NOFLASHSITE.com";
          </script>
    </div>
```

--- both of these load the alternative (http://www.NOFLASHSITE.com) regardless ..

any help is apreciated  - MW

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [SWFObject API](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/api), you could do something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
swfobject.addLoadEvent(function() {
    if (!swfobject.hasFlashPlayerVersion("9.0.18")) {
        window.location = "http://www.NOFLASHSITE.com";
    }
});
</script>
```

Make sure that script block is in the <head> of your html file, and replace the "9.0.18" with whatever minimum version of flash you require.

Comment: **RJ you are the man !!** 

that worked great!  thanks again  - MW